# mysql insert into a value of a another query

Tags: mysql, insert

Im new to PDO and trying to insert the result of a query into a table.

```
$statement_count_laeufer = $dbh->query('SELECT COUNT(Laeufer_Nachname)+1 FROM tbl_Laeufer;');
$result_count_laeufer = $statement_count_laeufer->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
```

This is my query that counts the entries of a column in a table and now i want to use the result into a INSERT INTO query

```
$statement = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_Lauf (FK_ID_Veranstaltung, FK_ID_Laeufer) VALUES (".$_POST[event].",  ".$result_count_laeufer." )
```

When I print/echo $statement_count_laeufer it shows me

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [COUNT(Laeufer_Nachname)+1] => 2203 ) )
```

But i just want to use the 2203.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: you specified for `fetchAll` to return a class. You need to get the value out of it or use PDO::FETCH_ARRAY instead. Also `prepare` is designed to use placeholders. You should read up on them instead of embedding variables in your query.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this;

```
$statement = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_Lauf (FK_ID_Veranstaltung, FK_ID_Laeufer) VALUES (".$_POST[event].",  (SELECT COUNT(Laeufer_Nachname)+1 FROM tbl_Laeufer)";
```

Mysql allows you use a `select` query result in an `insert` query